# Input select value, split and added into two new input value fields

Tags: jquery, forms, woocommerce

I got help in these forums (thank you) to fix the jquery to move one value (select menu) into a text field.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    function onchange() {
        var box1 = $("select[name=addon-8-choose-player-0]");
        var box2 = $("input[name*=addon-8-name-100-1]");
        console.log(box1);
        console.log(box2);
        box2.val(box1.val());
    }
    $("select[name=addon-8-choose-player-0]").on('change', onchange);
});
```

Now I have a new problem and that is that the plugin change the Select values into lowercase with -
A Select option "Playername, 3" becomes "playername-3-1" where the last number is just a field id.

I want to use the above script but modify it so "playername-3-1" (each option value) gets split into name and number (anything left of the first - and the number after the first -) and Capitalize (first letter) into two separate fields.

Left of "-" into box2 (and Capitalized)
Right of "-" and left of 2nd "-" into box3

How do I do that?

I'm a complete newbie (as you can tell) and trying learn as I go ahead. Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but I know so little about this I don't even know where to start to Google.

With the hope for mercy and help.

Reason for this entire approach is that I got a Woocommerce plugin for variable field input and I can't change the plugin...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this script.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
String.prototype.ucfirst = function()
{
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.substr(1);
}
function myFunction() {
    var box1 = $("select[name=addon-8-choose-player-0]");
    var box2 = $("input[name*=addon-8-name-100-1]");
    var str = this.value;
    var res = str.split("-");
    box2.val(res[0].ucfirst());
    box1.val(res[1]);
}
$("select[name=addon-8-choose-player-0]").on('change', myFunction);
});
```

So basically you can split the string using "-" and convert it into an array. Now you will have "player" in 0 index and "3" in 1st index. You can assign those values to box1 and box2. I have created a function `ucfirst()` to convert first letter in uppercase.Hope that helps.

Comment: You are a star. Thank you so much for your help. 
I added a box3 as well to use the number and it was so easy with your created array. 

The hero of the day <3

Comment: Glad to help. Thank you very much for the compliments. :) @Per